# Python: Creating a file-copy stripped from comments

Tags: python, file-io

Still new to Python, trying to follow a book example. This should create a text-file copy stripped from all the lines beginning with a # comment. It goes like (including my intern comments):

```
# this should be able to (create a file if not present yet and) take a file and then write another one with the same contents stripped off comments
# I wasnt able to bring it into a proper work - resulting file empty

f = open("test.dat","w")
# write several lines (the new-line n-symbol)
f.write("line one\nline two\nline three\n# blah blah \n# blah")
#
f.close()
# readline method reads all the characters up to and including the next newline character:
f = open("test.dat","r")
print ( f.read() )
print()
# readlines returns lines including newline character


newf = open("test2.dat","w")
newf.close()
newf = open("test2.dat","r")

while True:
  text = f.readline()
  if text == "":
    break
  if text == "#":
    continue
  newf.write(text)
f.close()
newf.close()

print()

newf = open("test2.dat","r")
print (newf.read())
newf.close()
```

But the resulting file is empty and has 0b. Could I humbly ask what is wrong? Thanks!

Comment: You're opening `test2.dat` for **reading** after you emptied it. Yet you try to write into it. However, you've also **read** the `test.dat` in its **entirety** and the file pointer is now set to the end of file, so there is nothing to be read, and the `f.readline()` will return empty string right away breaking your loop.

Comment: Perhaps some more **debug prints** could be used to see what code is being executed and why.

Comment: also, instead of while loop + readline(), you should probably use `for line in file:`

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the replies. I used this -while- because it was written like that in the book. Id prefer stick to what I was told to do. I have changed newf = open("test2.dat","w")
newf.close()
newf = open("test2.dat","r")
  into just newf = open("test2.dat","w") as well as did what J. Meijers said (which issues an error) but that didnt help. Still empty results.

Comment: FWIW, it makes the code easier to read (and write) if you use the `with` statement to open files. Of course, if you're working through a tutorial you should stick with what you've learned so far.

Comment: What's the name of the book you're using?

Comment: What book is this? This hasn't been idiomatic python during the last 15 years? I wouldn't recommend following such a book at all?

Comment: Is your last sentence a question? The book is called How to think like a computer scientist and so far has been very good written even for illiterates like me and moreover entertaining.

Comment: Actually it was written as a function in the book but as I was getting errors I simplified it a bit by putting it out of this function. I also call the variables by different names just in order not to feel like blindly rewriting the code...

Comment: I see, I've recommended that book before :( It seems that even the Python 3 edition uses these faulty constructs, I guess I need to update my recommended reading.

Comment: I didnt know that there was a P3 edition, that is my bad. I follow the P2 one and when meet something that the environment refuses to run, I google for P2 > P3 alternative. Perhaps I should switch the book.

Comment: Antti is just saying that using `f = open("test.dat","w")` instead of `with open("test.dat","w") as f:` is old-fashioned, less safe if something goes wrong with the file IO, and makes it harder to see the program structure. I guess it's ok for the book to _show_ you the old-fashioned way, but it should then show you the modern way, and encourage you to use it.

Comment: @PM2Ring not only that, but reading lines using `while True`.

Comment: Okay, thanks everybody. What I only dont understand is my question getting minus votes although I consider it correctly formulated and relevant to others that may encounter this particular problem (especially as it is a public tutorial one). Or is it for purely not knowing something that is obvious to veterans?

Comment: BTW, making minor modifications to the code, changing the variable names, etc, is an excellent way to learn. That book may be mostly fine, apart from this minor fault about file opening syntax; I don't know. I've heard good things about it, but I've never read it myself.

Comment: I really DO LIKE the boo. For people like me, who have never ever written a single line of code except some matrix addition in the 1st university grade, it is just perfect. I have written a few of my very own pet-codes during the last week and I have only started ten days ago. So Id definitely stay positive about it as a whole.

Comment: Don't be too concerned about 1 or 2 downvotes. Your question isn't fantastic, but I think it's fine.

Comment: I added the more idiomatic way to do it, too bad there is no such thing as a "Perfect Python self-learning book".

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I guess this book predates files being iterable, which is why it uses `.readline` in a `while True:` loop.

Comment: @PM2Ring nope, there is a Python 3 edition which still makes the mistake :(

Comment: You're doing very well for someone who's only been coding for 10 days.

Comment: Jewenile, there is [Think Python 2e](http://greenteapress.com/wp/think-python-2e/) which I believe is based on this book, available as PDF; the 2nd edition is for Python 3.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135270/discussion-between-antti-haapala-and-pm-2ring).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code had several problems:

- you opened the input file for reading and consumed all of it within `print(f.read())`; the file pointer was now positioned at the end of the file.
- the output file was opened for writing - but then closed right away, which created an empty file. This empty file was then opened *for reading*.
- your loop exited as soon as it started, as `readline()` at the end of a file will return an empty string `''`
- your `if` wouldn't have checked the first character of each line - instead matching the entire line against `#`. As the line also contains a newline character, not even `#` on a line would have matched this condition (`readline` would have returned `'#\n'`)

---

The idiomatic code for your case could be

```
with open('test.dat', 'w') as output_file:
    # write several lines (the new-line n-symbol)
    output_file.write("line one\nline two\nline three\n# blah blah \n# blah")
# file closed automatically

with open('test.dat') as input_file:
    print(input_file.read())
    print()
# closed automatically

# reopen input file, open output file
with open('test.dat') as input_file, open('test2.dat', 'w') as output_file:
    for line in input_file:
        if not line.startswith('#'):
            output_file.write(line) 
# both files again closed automatically at the end of with block

print('Contents of test2.dat are now:')
with open('test2.dat') as input_file:
    print(input_file.read())
```

Comment: Thanks. This "with - as" concept is completely new to me but seems very elegant.